# What parts do I need to build a good sounding audio circuit?

Tags: audio, dac

I'm building a soap dispenser which will contain a speaker playing various short sounds (1-5s). I'm very new to audio electronics, so I'm trying to figure out a good solution. The parts I know I will be using are the following

- 8 Ohm 1W speaker
- ATMEGA328P MCU

I've been experimenting quite a bit with a DFPlayer mini module (or rather a clone, MP3-TF-16P) but it seems glitchy and only appears to work when I run on 4xAA (I want to limit my supply voltage to 3xAA since I have components rated at max 5V, and using a voltage regulator would draw unnecessary current).

I guess I could try an "official" DFPlayer mini and try my luck with that, but I've also considered going with a more manual approach using an LM386 and an SD card reader.

**So, my main question is:**

Using

- 3xAA
- ATMEGA328P
- 8Ohm 1W speaker
- LM386 amplifier
- SD card reader

what more would I need to make a decent sounding audio player? I guess a DAC would be necessary? In that case any recommendation would be much appreciated.

Comment: "DF Mini Player" and "LM386" preclude any kind of "good sound."  One uses heavily compressed mp3 files, and the other is a crummy, ancient amplifier whose only reason for continued existence is that is cheap.

Comment: yeah, the LM386 is pretty much guaranteeing this won't sound good. An 8Ω 1W speaker is not *likely* to sound good. The MP3s won't make it any better. Also, batteries and LM386 is a bad combination, too. So, use a modern amplifier IC (for inspiration, go to diodes.com and look through the available ones that work with your supply voltage). I'm absolutely not clear which role the Atmega plays here, but it seems superfluous: a microcontroller fast enough to decode audio files probably also has all the capabilities you'd add with an Atmega328, anyways. Nothing won.

Comment: but honestly, a *soap dispenser doesn't need to sound good*. Your battery voltage and lifetime are still incompatible with the LM386, so kick that out. Replace your ATMega with a modern MCU that has enough flash to store a few short audio samples itself, and enough speed to decode them, as well as an I2S interface to feed an audio codec (some come with integrated amplifiers).

Comment: *would I need to make a decent sounding audio player?* Define "decent" for a few beeps, an ATMega328 might do but for anything more than that such an MCU is **by far** not powerful enough. It can only be used to control other modules like an MP3 player module. You can forget about anything better than cheap FM-radio like sound quality with the other components (LM386 and Speaker). But as mentioned in the comments, anything more is also overkill for a soap dispenser.

Comment: Sounds like switching to another MCU is the way to go. I've got my roots in quite basic Arduino stuff, and I'm pretty new to using the Atmega on its own. Any recommendation of an MCU that's suitable for audio playback?